# loading .xls Ms-Excel file in Webview Showing error

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I am trying to load a .xls Ms-Excel file in my `WebView` it showing error through `didFailWith error` delegates method the problem is i am unable to understand this error please help me.

Here is my code:-

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    [webView loadData:data MIMEType:@"application/vnd.ms-excel" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}
```

And Error is:-

```
    EXCEPTION CPMessageException: (null)
    2013-09-25 12:35:47.051 ewApps-dev18[1111:c07] [ReportsWebView_iPhone.m:116] did fail with error:- Error Domain=OfficeImportErrorDomain Code=912
 "Unknown exception" UserInfo=0x97a4970 
{NSErrorFailingURLKey=x-apple-ql-id://B7559867-1117-4FF5-8F61-015464D8E2C7/x-apple-ql-magic/, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=x-apple-ql-id://B7559867-1117-4FF5-8F61-015464D8E2C7/x-apple-ql-magic/, NSLocalizedDescription=Unknown exception}.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131430/reading-open-xml-documents-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

This is working code. 
`

```
UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1000, 760)];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
NSString *excl = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"xls"];
NSURL *exclURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:excl];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:exclURL];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
```

`

**Make sure your file is not password protected.**

Regarding your error check out error code [Error Code List](http://www.welovemacs.com/whdoalltherc.html)

Comment: reference link : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520137/displaying-ppt-doc-and-xls-in-uiwebview-doesnt-work-but-pdf-does)