# Got exception while reading doc file in UIWebViw

Tags: ios

I am trying to read .doc, .pdf file using UIWebView.

this is the function for read above file. but my issue is this function only work for .pdf file.

```
 -(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
   NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:nil];
   NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
   [webView loadRequest:request];
   [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
   [self.view addSubview:webView];
}
```

otherwise it throws exception at second line. because mainBundle method returns null path for temp.doc file.
actually temp.doc and temp.pdf files in same directory.

Appreciate for help

Comment: Try this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520137/displaying-ppt-doc-and-xls-in-uiwebview-doesnt-work-but-pdf-does

Comment: I have tried that link. I don't understand I got path for pdf file so why not for doc file.

Comment: move the .doc file to application directory may be to a different folder and  check the path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `file` `type` to differentiate with same file name

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"pdf"]; 
//OR
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"doc"];
```

Now method would be

```
-(void)loadDocument:(NSString*)documentName withFileTye:(NSString*)strFileType inView:(UIWebView*)webView
{
   NSString *strFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documentName ofType:strFileType];
   //Check if strFilePath object contains filepath
   if(strFilePath.length>0)
   {
      NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:strFilePath];
      NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
      [webView loadRequest:request];
      [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
      [self.view addSubview:webView];
   }
   else
   {
      NSLog(@"%@%@ doesnot exits",documentName,strFileType)
   }
}
```

**Note** : By using `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:ofType` file should be in application bundle and not in document or temprary directory

**If it shows file don't exist message then check `Target Membership` is ticked for that file.**

[image]

Comment: I have tried  that already but it throws same exception. also I tried with different file name

Comment: Did you check whether the file exists at the path?  
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:picturesPath]
should return true if the file exists.

Comment: Same Exception again Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:]: nil string parameter' @Prince

Comment: both files in main bundle. I have checked that file using show in finder. those file exists on that path. @Karthi