# Load or view .doc file in UIWebview in Ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, xcode7

I am trying to view `.doc` file from server url. It is giving me `unable to read document, error occurred` exception.

I am using Xcode 7.0.

I am trying this:

```
NSURL *myUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
[webView setDelegate:self];
NSURLRequest *myRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
[webView loadRequest:myRequest];
```

when I am trying to load `.pdf` or image files paths, it is working properly.

Comment: Once you save the document in iPhone then try to open it using UIDocumentinteractionController or QLPreviewController

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Displaying ppt, doc, and xls in UIWebView doesn't work but pdf does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520137/displaying-ppt-doc-and-xls-in-uiwebview-doesnt-work-but-pdf-does)

Comment: @nikhil84... here i'm not saving document in device. I'm doing direct load in webview.

Comment: Ok in that case I doc file doesnt work on UIWebView but pdf do as rightly shared in comment of Vishnu. So in your scenario you could download the files(any type) then preview it in QLPreviewController.

Answer (score 2):

```
    -(void)openFileUsingExtension:(NSString*)extension {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@temp.%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(),extension];
        NSLog(@"%@",path);

        if ([objectFromNSData writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) {
            NSLog(@"written");

            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
            NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
            [self.webview loadRequest:request];
            self.webview.scalesPageToFit = YES;
            self.webview.delegate = self;
            [self.view addSubview:self.webview]; 
        }
    }

then you can remove the file inside the UIWebViewDelegate method:

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@temp.%@",NSTemporaryDirectory(),extension];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:nil];
}
```

Comment: may I know what is "objectFromNSData" here?

Comment: NSURL *urlfile = [NSURL URLWithString:YourUrlString];
NSData * ObjectFromData = [NSData  dataWithContentsOfURL: urlfile];

Here ObjectFromData means NSData object